# How can I pin a manually-installed app to the Cinnamon panel?

Tags: cinnamon, panel

I'm using Devuan Daedalus, with the Cinnamon desktop environment, v5.6.7.

I've installed an app to `/foo/myapp` on my system, and have even created a start menu entry for it via the menu editor.

Now, I would like to have the icon/button for this app pinned to my panel - like I can do for many other apps (e.g. Firefox, Nemo, Quassel etc.), with right-click menu on the running app's panel button. Unfortunately - I don't get this option on the right-click menu for my new app.

Why is the 'pin to panel' menu entry missing? Is there something I need to do to "bless" this application so that I may pin it?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Cinnamon 5.2.7`, I am able to add via the command shell program `cinnamon-menu-editor` a new entry to the *applications* menu structure:

[image]

[image]

Afterwards I make a right-mouse click on that entry and say: `Add to panel`:

[image]